# Redirect to 404 if there is a question mark (?) in uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess

if have a problem with question mark example if i use this url /p=1 it matches, /p=a it doesn't matches but with /?p=a or anything after ? it will match. can you show me how to do it it .htaccess, thanks

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^\\?p=[0-9]+$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you show me the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`. Only the URI is matchable from there. If you need to match against it, use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=[0-9]+$
 RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```